# VS Code: How to move terminal to the left after Feb update

Tags: terminal, view, editor, panel, move

I would like to move the terminal/debug/ports panel to the **left** of the editor, **side-by-side** with the explorer. Previously, I just right-click the terminal and there is an option to do so. After the Feb update, it seems that I could only move it to the right side.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70982416/how-to-move-the-terminal-as-a-column-next-to-the-side-bar/70982514

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found another way to do it:
[image]

Comment: That is cool. Thanks for the reference. In the old version, we can quickly ctrl+B to open/fold the terminal. Hope they bring this back someday.