# How to move the terminal as a column next to the side bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After today 4.02.22 VSCode introduced the "Side panel" in update 1.64.0
It should give more flexibility and such, but in my case, it actually breaks my layout and takes the option that I was using out.

I have my layout - | Code | Terminal | Side bar |
Each in a column.
Now I cannot move the terminal anywhere but left as a column (before the code vide) and bottom.

Does anyone know how to revert this, or achieve my old layout?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing this in Insiders today 02/09/2022. Put the Side Bar on the right and use the command View: Move Panel Right. In one workspace with the setting `Workbench > Panel: Default Location` : `right` it put the Panel to the right of the Side Bar (so far right) but triggering the command fixed that. Editor | Terminal (Panel) | Side Bar. And working if put on the left too.

---

They are working on a fix for the change wrought by v1.64, should be in Insiders v1.65 02/08/2022 and as a recovery build to Stable later the same week if all goes well.

> So, I will be pushing a fix which is simply to bring back the ability
> to move the, as some have called it, primary panel. The plan for this
> fix is to release it into the insiders build tomorrow and the recovery
> build for stable later this week. Going forward, we will continue to
> improve the new side panel while playing nicely with the primary panel
> in different locations. Future changes will always be in insiders
> first, and we hope you continue to share your ideas with us.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141349#issuecomment-1033046397

---

Try creating a terminal in an editor "to the side" and then put the Side Bar on the right, like this:

[image: terminal on side with Side Bar]

There is a command: `Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area to the Side`.

And as you know the setting to put the Side Bar on the right.

> If you want to create more terminals in the same column, click the little lock icon first to unlock that group and then you can add more terminals in the same editor group/column.

This might be as close as you are going to get for now.  Upvote the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141349) about this.

Comment: Yep, moving a terminal as a tab was a great idea, not a solution, but definitely didn't occur to me. Thanks, I've upvoted the issue, hoping the old method comes back.

Comment: It would seem that its back to normal after updating today at 14 Feb (2022)

Answer (score 3):

I have another workaround to this:
[image]

Comment: Thats essentially the same workaround. Also, Im not sure you are using the latest version  of VSCode :)